# Stress testing mobile applications outline (iOS and Android) as a beginner using Jmeter?

Tags: android, ios, testing, jmeter

I'm looking into how to use jmeter (I've done manual testing until now) to perform stress testing on mobile applications.

In particular, I have a student management kind of app. Both (iOS - Swift) and (Android - Java) app are available.
I want to mimic lots of student trying to register for same course, leaving same course, paying etc. I'm not sure where to start, or how to even configure jmeter.
What should I request from the devs? Is android apk + ios testflight version enough or should I request full source code?
I feel lost as this is my first proper tech related job while in college, but the lack of resources is making me afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mimic network footprint of the mobile application.

First of all you need to identify which [network protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols)(s) is(are) being used by your application for communicating with the backend. You can ask the developers or use a [sniffer tool](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/ethical-hacking-sniffers/packet-sniffing-tools-for-mobile-devices) to capture and inspect the traffic.

Then you can choose a suitable JMeter [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)(s) to send the same requests as mobile application does.

If your application uses [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) protocol - you can even record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), for iOS you need to import JMeter's certificate and [enable full trust](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204477) for this. For Android you will need to take few more steps, check out [Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Configure-Android-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording) article for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the information, you gave me an idea of what more questions to ask... and things to consider, thank you.